# Weird HP bar over unreachable island?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

This is a pretty weird question regarding Fortnite BR. This started out with me seeing a lone island outside the very big normal one. Even if it wasent on the map, I wanted to see what happened when I went there. Of course, I died from touching water cause you cant get to the island and, I ended up dying early.

Now, about every 10-20 matches when the battle bus is aligned in a certain angle, before I launch (and after also) I see a weird HP bar over the unreachable island from about every angle I look from. Once I saw it as **(173/200 HP)**, and like 40 battles later, I see **(150/200HP)** Is this a glitch, or what is it?

*I couldnt provide a screenshot because the files where over 2 MB.*

Comment: You can resize images and/or save them in a different format (e.g. jpg) to make them smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This HP appears if you have damaged a building in the waiting lobby. Just like when you break trees and an HP bar appears, an HP bar also appears when you damage a building in the lobby. It should go away after a few seconds. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh I see. Weirdly, it shows always on top of that little island

Comment: Oh wow. I just realised that island was the spawn island. lol